# I am trying to get both landscape and portrait bottom safe area insets at once when the screen is loaded

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get bottom safe area insets for both portrait and landscape mode together when the screen is loaded. I know how to get the safe area inset for portrait mode when I am actually in portrait mode and landscape mode when I am actually in landscape mode separately.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
 let window = 
  UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
  let bottomPadding = 
  window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
}
```

This works good for that but I actually need this inset for both landscape and portrait mode irrespective of which mode I am actually in

Comment: What are you actually doing with the numbers? What is "device variable constraints"?

Comment: I am actually trying to set the gap/ vertical distance between a button and the view containing the button based on the bottom safe area inset.

Comment: And how does that require you to get the landscape safe area while you are not in landscape? What you are describing seems to be easily doable with autolayout.

Comment: I have created a view controller programmatically and it has several views , now inside one of the view I want to change the gap between the view and button based on the bottom inset of safe area , how to change the constraint based on the bottom inset for portrait or landscape mode we are in?

Comment: So you want a different constraint depending on the interface orientation? Override [`viewWillTransition(to:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition), and adjust your constraints there. It would _really_ help if you can describe your problem more concretely. As it is, your question is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: I was just curious is there way to know that even when I am in portrait mode

Comment: Makes no sense. You cannot query the environment about some other environment. You can ask how big the screen _is_, but if your app launches on an iPad you cannot ask it how big the screen _would be_ if this were an iPhone SE. The environment doesn't "know" that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think this is a very valid question. If I'm building a UI that has expensive layout calculations to be made and where the user can rotate from portrait to landscape, I would like to pre-calculate the UICollectionView section layouts for both landscape and portrait while the user is already sitting looking at a loading screen. At that point if it takes an extra half second they won't know or care. But when you rotate the device and the whole UI glitches to a halt that's a terrible experience.

Why are you not using Auto layout and compositional layouts (you may say), well maybe I am, and maybe they still simply don't manage my use cases. So maybe the above question would allow me to build a better user experience.